# Can not get token (OAUTH2, Spring, Kotlin)

Tags: java, spring, angular, kotlin, oauth-2.0

I try to get token but it not works. Request work in postman, but when I try reproduce this in angular I getting:

[image: error1]

My request in postman:

[image: error2]

My request in angular:

```
getToken() {
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ZGV2Z2xhbi1jbGllbnQ6ZGV2Z2xhbi1zZWNyZXQ=');
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append('username', 'Alex123');
body.append('password', 'password');
body.append('grant_type', 'password');

this.http.post<AuthToken>('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', body, {headers: headers})
  .subscribe(
    success => {
      debugger
      this.token = success.access_token;
    }
  );
}
```

my CORS configure, i thing all is good with it.:

```
   @Throws(Exception::class)
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll()
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/auth/token").permitAll()
}

@Bean
fun corsFilter(): FilterRegistrationBean<*> {
    val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
    val config = CorsConfiguration()
    config.allowCredentials = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*")
    config.addAllowedHeader("*")
    config.addAllowedMethod("*")
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
    val bean = FilterRegistrationBean(CorsFilter(source))
    bean.order = 0
    return bean
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have issues with CORS, please read the following article about to learn more about CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

This answer should be an comment, but I'm unable to comment..

Comment: add cors to questions body.

Comment: Could you provide me the response headers?

Comment: Could you try to add the OPTIONS method to the Access-control-allow-methods header? You are making a OPTIONS request, and only POST has been defined in this header. Information about this header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: I try it, but it did not work..

        val config = CorsConfiguration()
        config.allowCredentials = java.lang.Boolean.TRUE
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
        config.addAllowedHeader("*")
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST")
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)

Comment: What response headers did you received?

Comment: The Access-control-Allow-methods still doesn't contain OPTIONS. I'm not familiar with spring/kotlin. But I'm sure this causes your problems.

Comment: @mremil6 could you send me an update if this was the issue?

Comment: for now i use different cors configure and have new error.
I set withCredentials: true

https://imgur.com/a/2iIUDsp

if i use without credentials true i have: Post 401 error

in credentials i set client id as login and client secret as password, but i can not set grant type..